# Using setCellValueFactory on objects

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I've defined table:

```
    @FXML
    private TableView<FaAccount> tv_loro_nostro_accounts;
    private TableColumn<FaAccount, String> tc_acc_name;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<FaAccount, String> tc_currency;
```

and then setted setCellValueFactories (second part of second line is underlined in code, showing that there are some errors)

```
tc_acc_name.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new SimpleStringProperty(cellData.getValue().getName()));
tc_currency.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new SimpleObjectProperty<FaCurrency>(cellData.getValue().getCurrency()));
```

`setCellValueFactory` on `tc_currency` returns error:

```
bad return type in lambda expression: SimpleObjectProperty<FaCurrency> cannot be converted to ObservableValue<String>
```

in my mapping, currency is defined as

```
public class FaAccount implements Serializable {
...
    @Column(name = "CurrencyID")
    @Convert(converter = FaCurrencyToLongConverter.class)
    private FaCurrency currency;
    public FaCurrency getCurrency() {
        return currency;
    }
...
}
```

where `FaCurrency` is `enum`

```
public enum FaCurrency {

    UNKNOWN(null, "НЕИЗВЕСТНАЯ", "UNKNOWN"),
    USD(1L, "ДОЛЛАР США", "USD"),
    CNY(10000000001L, "КИТАЙСКИЙ ЮАНЬ", "CNY"),
    GBP(90001290L, "ФУНТ СТЕРЛИНОГОВ", "GBP");
...
}
```

What should I use in `setCellValueFactory`, so that it compiles without error?

Comment: Try `private TableColumn<FaAccount, FaCurrency> tc_currency;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the type of data you want to show on `tc_currency` column is `FaCurrency`, you need to define it as

```
private TableColumn<FaAccount, FaCurrency> tc_currency;
```